# How to write a single query for multiple tables having various columns resulting in the creation of rest api using python-django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I have several tables in my mysql database. I'm supposed to perform a single query for multiple tables having various columns resulting in the creation of rest api using 
`python-django`. I have created `rest api` for a single table but not for more than two tables. How can I solve this issue?

I tried solving using `queryset=model.objects.all()` but resulted in not knowing which model to use.
I also tried raw query but didn't get any result.

Kindly help me out with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_model function in Django and you can set which model using.

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
model = get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

Comment: I need a SQL query that can give me multiple details from "any" table I use. For eg I need to perform a "select org.name, job.name from org, name." how do I use this statement in django considering org and job are my tables in models.py and I need the SQL query to create the REST api?